# SQL databases beginner

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Hi I am interested in learning SQL databases something I should have done a long time ago but I kept avoiding it for some reason.I realized that there are diferent versions of SQL(MySQL , SQL-Server etc.)and now I am prety confused on witch one to learn.I would like to start learning SQL from w3school but to be honest I dont really know what to use for writing SELECT , DELETE statements and more importantly how to run it.I know that in order to create databases you need tables and I used Microsoft Acces for that but after creating the tables I don't know what to do next.I should mention that there are 2 reasons why I wana learn SQL:

1.For using it with PHP web development

2.I have a course at coledge in witch we study C# and I need to be able to learn how to create SQL databases so I can connect to them

Can you tell me what are the diferences beetween MySQL and SQL-Server?

What should I use for creating and manipulating databases?

And what resources or book could you recomend for learning SQL ?

Thanx in advance and sorry if my statements are vague I have never had anything to do with databases before

Comment: I applaud your desire to learn, but the questions that you ask are *far* too broad, and you should avoid asking multiple questions at the same time.

Comment: SQL Server would be an obvious fit with C#, both coming from Microsoft. May want to start off with SQL Server books online - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx

Comment: For learning don't rule out using PostgreSQL.  MySQL, Oracle, and Microsoft also all having lite or free developer versions to use.

Comment: This sort of question is most likely to receive helpful responses if posted on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check out [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems) in Wikipedia for a comparison of DBs. Things change regularly, but this can give you a good idea.

Second, you can use [PHP w/ MSSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx).

Third, you can use C# with MySQL, but in Visual Studio, it is very easy to use MSSQL and much more feature support.

As a student you can download all of the MS products you need from [Dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx) plus you can get a free subscription to PluralSight which is online video tutorials from beginner to advanced use of MS products.

PHP is fun and I've had more success using MySQL with PHP, but if you will have a class learning C# and MSSQL, you might as well start learning there.

Answer (score 2):

Both MySQL and Micorosoft SQL Server are so called Relational Database Management Systems (RDBMS). Data is structured in tables of rows and columns, and relations are made between the tables. MySQL is an open source solution, while SQL Server is not. There is however a free edition of Sql Server available called "Sql Server Express". You manage it through the software "Management Console", which I think is included in the download. http://www.microsoft.com/express

Both uses the SQL-language to interact with the stored data, they do have some differences though. SQL Server uses a variant called "T-SQL" while MySQL uses "SQL/PSM". The basics are however the same.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

since you use PHP, the best way you start is Mysql.
Check http://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/xampp.html

With XAMPP you can run your php apps and user PHP mysqladmin to learn more bout SQL syntax.

Good Luck